# area and fixed perimeter

Tags: geometry

I need help.

Can someone please explain and demonstrate in a very easy way why:

- With a fixed perimeter the equilateral triangle has a bigger area
- With a fixed perimeter square has a bigger area then a rectangle.

Could you use in the explanations also some formulas please?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a way without Am-Gm inequality?

Comment: Could you please tell it?